# Show Popup Menu on menu key event

Tags: android, keyevent, popupmenu

I have problem in creating pop-up menu on menu key event. I don’t understand how to pass required parameter to popmenu constructor. If any know what is the problem in my code then please suggest.

```
public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU) 
    {
        View v=getCurrentFocus();
        PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(this,v);
        popupMenu.inflate(R.menu.poupup_menu);
        popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(
            new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                    switch (item.getItemId()) {
                        case R.id.menu_red:
                            Toast.makeText(context,"red",2000).show();
                            break;
                        case R.id.menu_blue:
                            Toast.makeText(context,"red",2000).show();
                            break;
                        case R.id.menu_green:
                            Toast.makeText(context,"red",2000).show();
                            break;
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            });
            popupMenu.show();

            // ...
            return true;
        } else {
            return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Which parameter do you want to pass. Have you tried anything else? Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: @AabidMulani thanks for answering see this constructor   PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(this,v); i have anable pass view object on key event...if you know better solution than this please give some suggestion

Comment: for which View you want to handle this KeyEvent?

Comment: i want to show popupmenu When i Click on menu of device....And i am talking about popupmenu constructor in that two parameter there one is context and other is view.and view it want id.if u know how to do  show popupmenu When i Click on menu of device then please suggest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks guys for answering...I got perferct solution to handle android menus..Override onCreateoption menu method,in that get menu instance and inflate our customize menu..and handle menu click event.

> ```
>      /* Initiating Menu XML file (menu.xml) */
> @Override
> public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
> {
>     MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
>     menuInflater.inflate(R.layout.menu, menu);
>     return true;
> }
> ```

```
/**
 * Event Handling for Individual menu item selected
 * Identify single menu item by it's id
 * */
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{

    switch (item.getItemId())
    {
    case R.id.menu_bookmark:
        // Single menu item is selected do something
        // Ex: launching new activity/screen or show alert message
        Toast.makeText(AndroidMenusActivity.this, "Bookmark is Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    case R.id.menu_save:
        Toast.makeText(AndroidMenusActivity.this, "Save is Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    case R.id.menu_search:
        Toast.makeText(AndroidMenusActivity.this, "Search is Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    case R.id.menu_share:
        Toast.makeText(AndroidMenusActivity.this, "Share is Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    case R.id.menu_delete:
        Toast.makeText(AndroidMenusActivity.this, "Delete is Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    case R.id.menu_preferences:
        Toast.makeText(AndroidMenusActivity.this, "Preferences is Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```